# Magento 2 randomly applying wrong custom layout

Tags: magento2, layout, custom, cms, page-layouts

I have got an issue applying custom layout to a CMS page.
I am on Magento 2.2.0 Enterprise edition on a multiserver stack.

Here is my configuration :

**File** `Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/full_width.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlClass="full_width_content" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

**File** `Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/layouts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="full_width">
        <label translate="true">Full width</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

**File** `Vendor/Theme/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Theme" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

On the CMS page configuration I chose `Design` > `Layout` > `Full width`

The expected result will be the `<main #maincontent/>` element having the class `.full_width_content` but sometimes I have the default class `.page-main` defined in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml`

Over 10 page loading I have:

- 1 time `<main id="maincontent" class="page-main"></main>`
- 9 times `<main id="maincontent" class="full_width_content"></main>`

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?
Do you have any ideas for testing and debugging?
Is that a configuration issue?

Thank you!